# Android SQlite not updating the data

Tags: android, android-sqlite

My DatabaseHandler Class:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "debugger";

    //database version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    //database name;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "appdb";

    private static final String TABLE_PROJECT = "projects";     
    //Project Table Columns
    private static String PROJECT_ID = "Project_id";
    private static final String PROJECT_NAME = "Name";
    private static final String PROJECT_DESCRIPTION = "Description";
    private static final String CLIENT_NAME = "Client_Name";
    private static final String LOCATION = "Location";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Executing OnCreate");   
        createProjectTable(db);     
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {      

    }

    private void createProjectTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
        String CREATE_PROJECT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PROJECT + "("
        + PROJECT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
        + PROJECT_NAME + " TEXT, "
        + PROJECT_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, "
        + CLIENT_NAME + " TEXT, "
        + LOCATION + " TEXT );";
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Creating Project table --> " + CREATE_PROJECT_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PROJECT_TABLE);
    }   

    public void addProject(Project project){
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         values.put(PROJECT_NAME, project.getName()); // Contact Name
         values.put(PROJECT_DESCRIPTION, project.getDescription()); // Contact Phone
         values.put(CLIENT_NAME, project.getClient_name());
         values.put(LOCATION, project.getLocation());
         // Inserting Row
         Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Inserting Project....");
         db.insert(TABLE_PROJECT, null, values);
         Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Inserted successfullyt....");
         db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public List<Project> getProjects(){
        List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<Project>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PROJECT;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if(cursor.getCount() != 0){
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Projects found...");
          if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Project project = new Project();
                project.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                project.setClient_name(cursor.getString(2));
                project.setDescription(cursor.getString(3));
                project.setLocation(cursor.getString(4));
                projects.add(project);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
          }
        }
      return projects;
    }

    public void updateProject(Project project){
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         values.put(PROJECT_NAME, project.getName()); // Contact Name
         values.put(PROJECT_DESCRIPTION, project.getDescription()); // Contact Phone
         values.put(CLIENT_NAME, project.getClient_name());
         values.put(LOCATION, project.getLocation());
         String where = PROJECT_ID + " = ? ";       
         String [] value = { String.valueOf(project.getProject_id()) };
         try{
             int count = db.update(TABLE_PROJECT, values, where , value);
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Updated rows -> " + count);
         }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        db.close();
    }
}
```

In my activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(...);
dbHelper = new DatabaseHandler(this);
}
```

and when user clicks update button I call update method

```
dbHelper.updateProject(newProject);
```

In my `updateProject` method in `dbHelper` the value of count is 0.

And `dbHelper.getProjects()` returns me old values even if this method is called after update method.

I have checked using debugger that new values are passed to the `updateProject` method but they are not getting reflected. The method `addProject` works fine.

The Project class

```
public class Project implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int project_id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String client_name;
    private String location;

    public Project(){

    }

    public Project(int project_id, String name, String client_name,String description, String location){
        this.project_id = project_id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.client_name = client_name;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public int getProject_id() {
        return project_id;
    }

    public void setProject_id(int project_id) {
        this.project_id = project_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getClient_name() {
        return client_name;
    }

    public void setClient_name(String client_name) {
        this.client_name = client_name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

}
```

Anyone help please.

Comment: Post your getProject_id() method too...

Comment: Please check the DB for the existence of the to be updated "PROJECT_ID" row record.

Comment: The row exists as it is a row in a listview which gets populated from database.

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
 String [] value = { Integer.toString(project.getProject_id()) };
```

Comment: should we have a common dbHelper object among the activities? I am creating new object for each activity.

Answer (score 1):

Use this -

```
String[] value = new String []{ String.valueOf(project.getProject_id()) };
```

Comment: What is the data that you have inserted? Also what data are you trying to update?. Row count = 0 in update means - "nothing is getting updated". Please check the parameters you are passing in update.

Comment: The data is a item in listview. It gets populated from database. The parameter I am passing is an object with updated values.

Comment: The code is running fine for me. I am able to update also. Looks like there is some issue with the Project object populating from the listview . Please check...

Comment: I checked..the project object returns the correct id and other values. Not sure what is wrong :(

Comment: Nope I dont know how to make it work :( It just doesnt update the row in database. Update method always returns zero.

Answer (score 1):

The project id is of int data type so you should use

```
  int value = project.getProject_id();
```

Comment: you should look up documentation for update method so you will know what I am trying to do

Comment: you will have to use db.update(TABLE_PROJECT, values, PROJECT_ID+"="+value, null);