# ListView notifyDatasetChanged does not refresh view

Tags: android, listview

In my application, I tried to update the listview by

```
adater.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But it does not work.

I know people have met this problem like this: [Android ListView not refreshing after notifyDataSetChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503006/android-listview-not-refreshing-after-notifydatasetchanged)

But I have tried that method, it does not work for me.

This is my core codes(I tried to refresh the view once the drawer is opened):

```
public class DrawerItem {
    private String name;
    private int icon = -1;
    private String counter = "0";
    private boolean showCounter;
    private ItemType itemType;

    public DrawerItem(String name, int icon, ItemType itemType, boolean showCounter) {
        this.name = name;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.showCounter = showCounter;
        this.itemType = itemType;
    }
    //getter and setter omitted
    public enum ItemType {
        Action, Layer, Title
    }
}


private List<DrawerItem> getDrawerItems() {
    ArrayList<DrawerItem> items = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();

    DrawerItem layer = new DrawerItem("Layer", -1, DrawerItem.ItemType.Title, false);
    DrawerItem layer01 = new DrawerItem("Layer01", R.drawable.drawer_ic1, DrawerItem.ItemType.Action, false);
    DrawerItem layer02 = new DrawerItem("Layer02", R.drawable.drawer_ic2, DrawerItem.ItemType.Action, true);
    DrawerItem layer03 = new DrawerItem("Layer03", R.drawable.drawer_ic3, DrawerItem.ItemType.Action, true);
    DrawerItem layer04 = new DrawerItem("Layer04", R.drawable.drawer_ic4, DrawerItem.ItemType.Action, false);


    items.add(layer);
    items.add(layer01);
    items.add(layer02);
    items.add(layer03);
    items.add(layer04);
    if (mLayerPoint2 != null) {
        layer02.setCounter(String.valueOf(mLayerPoint2.getFeatureCounter()));
    }

    if (mLayerPoint3 != null) {
        layer03.setCounter(String.valueOf(mLayerPoint3.getFeatureCounter()));
    }
    return items;
}

private class DrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DrawerItem> {
    private List<DrawerItem> mData = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
    public DrawerAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }
    public void swapItems(List<DrawerItem> items) {
        this.mData.clear();
        this.mData.addAll(items);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        DrawerItem item = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            switch (item.getItemType()) {
                case Action:
                    convertView = ((LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.drawer_item_action, null);
                    .....
                    break;
                case Title:
                    convertView = ((LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.drawer_item_title, null);
                    ...
                    break;
            }
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}


public void onCreate(...){
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mDrawerListAdapter = new DrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_item_action);
    List<DrawerItem> items = getDrawerItems();
    mDrawerListAdapter.addAll(items);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mDrawerListAdapter);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            mDrawerListAdapter.swapItems(getDrawerItems());
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: where are you calling notifyDatasetchanged? please post that code as well

Comment: method `swapItems` in class `DrawerAdapter`

Comment: Did you post the complete code for your adapter?

Comment: try invalidating the list view.

Comment: Yes, the adapter code is complete.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

Caused from my f**ing stupid `getView` method of the `DrawerAdapter`:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    DrawerItem item = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        switch (item.getItemType()) {
            case Action:
                convertView = ((LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.drawer_item_action, null);
                .....
                break;
            case Title:
                convertView = ((LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.drawer_item_title, null);
                ...
                break;
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Fix it to:

```
    switch (item.getItemType()) {
        case Action:
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = ((LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.drawer_item_action, null);
            }
            ....
            break;
        case Title:
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = ((LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.drawer_item_title, null);
            }
            ....
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with you swapItems ,You really not required to explicitly call the notifyDataSetChanged. 
if your using ArrayAdapter.

Since when you add an item to ArrayAdapter , the ListView will be notified on the changes.
So you have to add the item to the adapter.

Remove this line and the swapItems() method in the DrawerAdapter.

```
private List<DrawerItem> mData = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
```

When you need to refresh with new item, clear the existing item in the adapter and add new items from onDrawerOpened()

*So, your onDrawerOpened() need to be changed as below*

```
 public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        // clear the existing items
        mDrawerListAdapter.clear();
        // add the new item
        mDrawerListAdapter.addAll(getDrawerItems())
    }
```

Thats all.. Hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks,I tried that, but I found that the `counter` of the item does not updated. It seems that the `getView` is not called again.

Comment: Does getDrawerItems() size >0 ?

Comment: Of course, you can check my `getDrawerItems` method, it will add five item to the list.

Comment: Try to override getCount() and see if its called

Comment: `getCount` is called, and it return five.

Comment: Ok.If getCount() is called , then issue seems to be something different. can you also try override getItemViewType() and return 1. (just a try :)