# Android change order of cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, location

I googled a lot but didn't find any answer to my problem:

I got a Cursor that queries a table that contains a latitude and a longitude. I want to order a ListView by the distance to the user. The second answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7261601/3879470) showed me how to order by distance.

But now let's say the user moves and the second item is now more near than the first one. How can I reorder my list now?

Not sure if i could provide any code that would be helpful, because it's more or less a generic question.

thanks alot

Comment: every time the user moves you need to requery and the the calculations all over again

Comment: `The second answer in this thread` ... hehehe ... order of  the answers is changing dynamically

Comment: @Selvin but the order by is a String that is definded once in the onCreateView method of my fragment. this means it will always be ordered by the starting point.

Comment: @tyczj how would I do that?

Comment: what do you mean how do you do that, you know how to do it the first time so just do the same thing again

Comment: When you calculated the distance first time using the current location(in lattitude and longitude), then when the user moves to another location get the new location of user and recalculate latitude and longitude.

Comment: so you mean that i should call changeCursor? i don't think that this is a good idea

Comment: @MohammedAli yes, obviously. But the question is: How do I reorder it? How do I notify the Cursor or Adapter that the" order by" value has changed?

Comment: to notify adapter of changes see these: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3669325/3879470  http://stackoverflow.com/q/14503006/3879470

Answer (score 0):

If the ordering is defined as a calculation in SQL, then I think you'll have to requery. (The cursor will not dynamically recalculate the "ORDER BY" clause, this happens at query time in SQL).

Alternatively, you could change your adapter to one backed by a list instead of a cursor, and implement a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to sort the data. Then notify the adapter that the data has changed. Assuming each row in the list is backed by an object of type Item:

```
Collections.sort(listOfItems,new Comparator<Item>(){
public int compare(Item i1, Item i2){
    /* Compare your items here. Return
     * -1 if i1 < i2
     *  0 if i1 = i2
     *  1 if i1 > i2
     */
}});
```

Comment: as i mentioned, i am working with a Cursor, so I am using a CursorAdapter. That's why i cant use a comparator