# Update listview?

Tags: android, image, listview

How can i update my listview, every time i add images to sdcard it's not showing I need to run my app again to see the pictures. Can you please help me thanks.

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.acmain);

    sharedpreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    frameChooserGV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    utils = new UtilsList(ListViewImage.this.getApplicationContext());
    InitializeGridLayout();
    framePaths = utils.getFilePaths();
    frameChooserAdapter = new ListViewImageAdapter(
            ListViewImage.this.getApplicationContext(), framePaths,
            columnWidth);
    frameChooserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    frameChooserGV.setAdapter(frameChooserAdapter);
    frameChooserGV.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void InitializeGridLayout() {
    Resources r = getResources();
    float padding = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            AppConstant.GRID_PADDING, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    columnWidth = (int) ((utils.getScreenWidth() - ((AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS + 1) * padding)) / AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("" + frameChooserGV.getPositionForView(view), "" + position);
    Intent b_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            com.example.customize.CustomizeNumberDisplay.class);
    b_intent.putExtra("position", position);
    startActivity(b_intent);

}
```

Comment: call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh your list after updating the data that populates your list.

Comment: I try to put it "frameChooserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();" but it's not working.

Comment: where did you put that line of code? You need to update the data that populates list then refresh listview

Comment: i just put it in onCreate, i dont know where should i put . hehe

Comment: read activity lifecycle. onCreate is called once during the lifecycle of the activity until it is destroyed. So it is expected to work that way. you need to decide how you want to refresh. Study activity lifecycle

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to refresh Android listview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

> myListView.invalidateViews();  in on Resume method, this will help to create view Again in listview android. Or  also Call  `notifyDataSetChanged();`  on your Adapter

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your Adapter object once you've modified the data in that adapter.

Source : [How to refresh Android listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview)

And also :

[Android ListView not refreshing after notifyDataSetChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503006/android-listview-not-refreshing-after-notifydatasetchanged)