# Refreshing ArrayAdapter when backend data has changed, but item value has not

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, picasso

I am using an `ArrayAdapter` along with `ListView` to display some images (I use Picasso to help with image handling). The images are initially loaded from the state on the local device. The adapter has `ids` for the images, which the `getView()` method of the adapter uses to get the path. If the image is not available locally, the local state returns an URL for the image. If the URL has expired, I need to fetch this from the backend.

If the URL is not expired, I have no issues, as I can either directly provide the path to Picasso or the URL and Picasso will handle everything for me. However, when I need to fetch the URL from the backend, I need to do this asynchronously. After fetching the URL, I tried doing the following but it doesn't seem to work (my `getView()` will in this case use Picasso with the URL):

```
        adapter.remove(id);
        adapter.add(id);
```

`notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't seem to do much as well.

What is the best way to handle this situation? Is there any other way than what I am trying to do with the adapters? I want to delay the URL fetch from the backend as much as possible, basically until the user needs to see the image.

UPDATE: for now, I am replacing the `id` with a `temp_id` when the URL is expired and then add the correct `id` again, when I have the valid URL so that the view gets refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing your ArrayList of image urls with myArray.clear()? Not so sure if I get your question or how your code looks like.

But I have issues like this before. What worked for me was to repopulating the adapter completely.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503006/android-listview-not-refreshing-after-notifydatasetchanged) should help.

Comment: I was worried about keeping a pointer to the data as the base classes could just copy the Arraylist at some point (even though the code doesn't do this at the moment). If I try to keep my own copy, I will have to override all the add/remove methods to make sure my copy is in sync (wanted to try and avoid this mess). Will try out the clear() approach, but IIRC, I did try this and it didnt work.