# How to notifydatasetchanged between two activities

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, notifydatasetchanged

I have two activities that each contain fragments. Activity A has a fragment with a ListView. Rows of the ListView are obtained from a SQLiteDatabase.

Activity B contains a fragment that enables entries of the database to be edited. When a user edits a database entry, saves the data, then returns to Activity A via the backbutton or:

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

How do I notify the ListView in Activity A that there has been a change to the database? I understand how to communicate between an Activity and it's fragments, but how do I implement a notifydatasetchanged when the fragments are in two different activities?

I suspect that going back to Activity A via the back button is simply recalling the view from the stack, but that view has changed when there is a database change.

Comment: requery the dataset in onResume in the activyty A.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ListView not refreshing after notifyDataSetChanged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503006/android-listview-not-refreshing-after-notifydatasetchanged)

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer as it may be helpful for other having the same question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply call the `notifyDataSetChanged` in `onResume` in your Activity A. So when you close or go back from Activity B to A, it will update the data. Don't forget to check if the adapter is different than null, otherwise it could crash the first time you open the App.

You could also make a public function in your Activity A which updates the list and call it from your Activity B.

```
class ActivityA

public static void updateList() {
    if(adapter != null){
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged;
    }
}


class ActivityB

ActivityA.updateList();
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read the updated dataset from your SQLite database and pass it adapter again. After you need to notify adapter. For example, like in the code below:

In your Activity A

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // method to read new dataset
    Database ourDB = new Database(this);
    ourDB.openDB();
    data = ourDB.getData();
    ourDB.closeDB();

    if(adapter == null) {
        // initializes adapter when first launched
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(data, this);
        yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    else {
        // in subsequent returns to activity we are replacing 
        // old data with new and reusing existing adapter
        adapter.updateData(data);
    }

}
```

In your adapter class include similar method:

```
public void updateData(ArrayList<String> newData) {
    data = newData;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: @user2254532 Did you solve your problem? If not have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 0):

you could start activity with startActivityForResult(start activityB) and override method onActivityResult in activityA and notifyDataSetChanged when needed.