# Correct way to refresh a ListView adapter in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, baseadapter

I have a list of items. I have a button that sends you to another activity in order to create a new item. When the new item is saved an intent sends you back to the activity with the list where the new item should be added. The adapter extends from BaseAdapter without filtering, it just sets the data to the views.

My code is this:

```
onCreate(){
    ListView listView = findItemById......
    listView.setListeners.......
}

onResume(){
    data = getData();
    adapter = new ListAdapter(context,data);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

It works but is this correct?

Can I use creation of adapter and setAdapter in onCreate and use notifyDataSetChanged() only in onResume somehow?

Comment: sure, you can create your adapter in `onCreate`, call `setAdapter` there and call `notifyDataSetChanged` inside `onResume`

Comment: It depends on how `ListAdapter` is implemented ... fx: if it extends ArrayAdapter and it's using filtering (the only reason to extending from ArrayAdapter not from BaseAdapter) then well it may not work but if you are  extending BaseAdapter and using passed `data` references directly then yes ... rember that if you do `data = getData();` it will not work as after this `data` would be a different reference then passed to Adapter previously

Comment: You might find this helpful :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503006/android-listview-not-refreshing-after-notifydatasetchanged

Comment: Is the above a bad practice?

Comment: sort of `a bad practice` but if it works then dont worry...

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct way to do it is a use

```
startActivityForResult(...)
```

method to launch your Second activity (where your new items is added).

And in your second activity use

```
setResults(RESULT_OK or RESULT_CANCELLED)
```

(diffrent result when new items is added or user just back to prev screen).

Then in your ListAdapter class add method

```
public void updateData(List data) {
    this.data = new ArrayList<>(data);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And call it in your onActivityResults(...)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        adapter.updateData(...your data from result Intent, or from anywhere else...);
    }
}
```

**Also i strongly recommend you to use RecyclerView instead of ListView**

**UPD:** to answer your question - i think that biggest mistake in your code, is to create new instance of ListAdapter object in onResume() method, when it's not necessary

Answer (score 1):

Add this method to your adapter and then call it with new data using `adapter.udpateData(data)`:

```
public void updateData(List data) {

  this.data = data;
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Also, you can use **`notifyItemRangeInserted(0, data.size())`**

Answer (score 0):

Hi OnActivityResult  read all data create the new object and add to the list and call notifyDatasetChanged() , i will automatically refresh ui