# Adding new item to ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

I want to add a new item to my `arrayadapter` and then for it to render in my view. After digging online, I noticed that the ArrayAdapter class keeps its own version of the `arraylist` as mentioned here: [Android ListView not refreshing after notifyDataSetChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503006/android-listview-not-refreshing-after-notifydatasetchanged).

Heres my code:

`The add new item code:`

```
public void addRecordSet(View view) {

    RecordStats recordStats = new RecordStats();
    recordStats.RecordID = mRecord.id;

    long recordStatId = mDatabaseHelper.addRecordStats(recordStats);
    recordStats.ID = (int) recordStatId;

    recordStatsList.add(recordStats);
    mAdapter.swapRecordFormList(recordStatsList);
}
```

`The arrayadapter code:`

```
    public void swapRecordFormList(ArrayList<RecordStats> recordStatsList) {
        mRecordStatsList = recordStatsList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

However, i get this error:

```
Process: com.example.andyxu.enzo3, PID: 19289

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View recordForm = convertView;
    if (recordForm == null) {
        recordForm = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_record_form, parent, false);
    }

    RecordStats currentRecord = mRecordStatsList.get(position);

    EditText reps = (EditText) recordForm.findViewById(R.id.reps);
    if (currentRecord.Reps > 0) {
        reps.setText(String.valueOf(currentRecord.Reps));
    }

    EditText weight = (EditText) recordForm.findViewById(R.id.weight);
    if (currentRecord.Weight > 0) {
        weight.setText(String.valueOf(currentRecord.Weight));
    }
    return recordForm;
}
```

Comment: where do you get? Can you post that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter` can be backed by a live list object that you provide. (So the link you referenced is not quite relevant to your situation). With an `ArrayAdapter` all you need to do is call `add` on the backing list object and then call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adatper = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.layout, list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

list.add("Another item");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Hmm... I did that initially and it worked but whenever I add a new item, its values are defaulted to the previous item in that list which is not what I want. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps an issue with `getView` if that's being overridden? Could you post the full code.

Comment: Added the `getView` function. @jspcal

Comment: Nvm, I am an idiot. I figured out my problem haha. Thanks for helping me