# Search filter does not display searched items in listview

Tags: android

I am making an app that will let the user add their picture and names and then display it to the listview. In addition, I have also added a functionality for them to search..

The code is working perfectly fine when creating search filter, however, when I added an sqlite database to it, it messes up. When I try to search, it will not show anything but all the added data to the list.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
DatabaseHelper db;

        Uri imageUri;
        EditText textsearch;
        ListView lv;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        ArrayList<Names> list = new ArrayList<Names>(); //this is my reference list
        ArrayList<Names> displaylist = new ArrayList<Names>(); //arraylist to display all data
        ArrayList<Names> anotherlist = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Names> findlist = new ArrayList<>();
        Adapter adapter;
        private Names names = new Names();

        private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            textsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textsearch);
            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

            db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            displaylist = db.getAll();

            adapter = new Adapter(this, displaylist);
            madapter = new Adapter(this,findlist);
            final Adapter myadapter = new Adapter(this, list);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            //
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

            this.textsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    list.clear();
                    String s1 = s.toString();
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(s1);

                    for (int i=0; i<displaylist.size(); i++){
                        String find = displaylist.get(i).getName().toLowerCase();
                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(find);
                        if(matcher.find()){
                            list.add(displaylist.get(i));
                            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }//end if
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Can you please remove unused lists and adapters in this case, so that we can better troubleshoot. Are you using madapter and myadapter ?

Comment: Yes I will edit it. I am using `adapter`

Comment: Please perform instantiation inside the onCreate() or appropriate methods. As for troubleshooting your data from the database not displaying, can you do a simple system . out . println on the read data? let’s start there and see if you’re actually reading any data back from the dB.

Comment: @EvOlaNdLuPiZ the one that is not displaying is only when I try to search an item. But as of the actual items on my database, I can see it.

Comment: I took a glance at your search routines after the listener. I’d like to make the suggestion to still do print outs for debugging, it won’t hurt. However, for this from what I’ve read/experienced that notifyDataSetChanged() would be worthwhile looking into. You do setAsapter after instantiation, this is reasonable, but you also do it in the listener...then notifyDataSetChanged. Do you see what I’m pointing you to?

Comment: (Link to SO similar question)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503006/android-listview-not-refreshing-after-notifydatasetchanged]